# Is it possible to change the Operating System of the K599 (chinese iPhone)

Tags: operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have an electronic device the model is K599 was built in China. The operating system of this device is a minimalist FreeBSD with java installed. I would like to know if is possible to change the operating system from Actual FreeBSD to Google Android.

**Another doubt:** Is it possible to install a new operating system inside the SD memory card?

I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Does someone have the same problem?

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Most chinese mobiles run on a processor like MTK62xx, which uses a MIPS instruction set. That's a possible hardware plattform for a Linux kernel to run on. Yet those phones are not equiped with enough memory to run Android. Android needs a lot more than the internal 90MB flash disk. And I assume the actual RAM is 32MB or less (judging from my last two and the remaining free Java mem.)

Your K599 does not run FreeBSD. That's a misinformation. The software and UI you see is a customized [MTK/NucleuOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787838/how-to-start-develop-for-chinese-mobile-phones-based-on-nucleus-rtos-mtk). There's no known way to run custom software, much less a complete foreign OS off the microSD.

There is the "Q8 / iRobot" chinese mobile, which runs a genuine Android 1.5 variant. But that was specifically designed for that, albeit I think it runs on a secondary MTKxxxx chip too. But all the other mobiles, specificall with dual sim/gsm modules are unlikely to ever will.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was everything I was in need to listen. Very good answer.

Comment: I have something very strange, when I use a network scan (like nessus) it find my device, and the operating system of it accuses to be FreeBSD.. it is very strange to me. or my scan is little bittle not well calibrated.. :-) anyway thank you very much, because I'm not to going waste my time trying to develop anything to this kind of chinese device. The best way to get some app to chinese device is JAVA.. yeah?

Comment: @FernandoCosta: It's very likely that all MTK phones actually use the TCP/IP networking stack from *BSD, so that might explain it being detected as FreeBSD. My OS fingerprinting tests with `nmap -O` were inconclusive. -- But you can run a couple of J2ME applications, yes. Opera Mini for example works well, but you'll have to be patient with both games and utility applications. -- Also btw, the "H6" or "A3000" are genuine chinese Android 2.1 mobiles.

Comment: nice tip, I learned one thing more about my chinese device. I have already opera mini and really work so well. Also I have skype working on my device, it is really funny but is true. But untill now I can't use the skype very well, sound like the program have a bug on calibration.. and I can't touch the functions..  anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it is not possible (ever heard Android running on iPhone?), as long as someone writes a driver for it. However, if your device is a niche device, then it might not have enough user support to attract an experienced driver developer to release an Android driver for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This kind of device is very popular speacially in Asia, in south america is not so popular, but have a lot.. I ll give a try. Thanks again.